# Phase 4 Binary Bomb

Tags: assembly

My partner and I have been working on phase 4 of the Binary Bomb Lab and have gotten quite stuck.  We have referred to prior posts, but none of them have clarified our issue, which is regarding line 81.  We have figured out that this phase requires two double inputs, and that function 4 returns the position (of a number, maybe the second input?) in the Fibonnaci Sequence.  We can get to line 84 using inputs (2,4), but then naturally it is directed to explode_bomb.  We would appreciate any help/guidance because we are super stuck!!! Thanks!

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
   0x08048dad <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048dae <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048db0 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
=> 0x08048db3 <+6>: lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048db6 <+9>: mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048dba <+13>:    lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048dbd <+16>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048dc1 <+20>:    movl   $0x804a1ca,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048dc9 <+28>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048dcc <+31>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048dcf <+34>:    call   0x8048758 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048dd4 <+39>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048dd7 <+42>:    jne    0x8048de6 <phase_4+57>
   0x08048dd9 <+44>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048ddc <+47>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048ddf <+50>:    jle    0x8048de6 <phase_4+57>
   0x08048de1 <+52>:    cmp    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048de4 <+55>:    jle    0x8048deb <phase_4+62>
   0x08048de6 <+57>:    call   0x8049108 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048deb <+62>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048dee <+65>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048df2 <+69>:    movl   $0x8,(%esp)
   0x08048df9 <+76>:    call   0x8048af0 <func4>
   0x08048dfe <+81>:    cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048e01 <+84>:    je     0x8048e08 <phase_4+91>
   0x08048e03 <+86>:    call   0x8049108 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048e08 <+91>:    leave  
   0x08048e09 <+92>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.



Dump of assembler code for function func4:
=> 0x08048af0 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048af1 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048af3 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
   0x08048af6 <+6>: mov    %ebx,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048af9 <+9>: mov    %esi,-0x8(%ebp)
   0x08048afc <+12>:    mov    %edi,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x08048aff <+15>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%esi
   0x08048b02 <+18>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048b05 <+21>:    test   %esi,%esi
   0x08048b07 <+23>:    jg     0x8048b10 <func4+32>
   0x08048b09 <+25>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x08048b0e <+30>:    jmp    0x8048b39 <func4+73>
   0x08048b10 <+32>:    cmp    $0x1,%esi
   0x08048b13 <+35>:    je     0x8048b39 <func4+73>
   0x08048b15 <+37>:    mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048b19 <+41>:    lea    -0x1(%esi),%eax
   0x08048b1c <+44>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048b1f <+47>:    call   0x8048af0 <func4>
   0x08048b24 <+52>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x08048b26 <+54>:    mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048b2a <+58>:    sub    $0x2,%esi
   0x08048b2d <+61>:    mov    %esi,(%esp)
   0x08048b30 <+64>:    call   0x8048af0 <func4>
   0x08048b35 <+69>:    add    %eax,%edi
   0x08048b37 <+71>:    add    %edi,%ebx
   0x08048b39 <+73>:    mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x08048b3b <+75>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%ebx
   0x08048b3e <+78>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%esi
   0x08048b41 <+81>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%edi
   0x08048b44 <+84>:    mov    %ebp,%esp
   0x08048b46 <+86>:    pop    %ebp
   0x08048b47 <+87>:    ret
```